# How to get around Xcode managed provisioning file expiration every 6 days

Tags: xcode, apple-developer

First, let me tell you I've browsed *sooo* many StackOverflow sites to solve this issue. I have found nothing that works/is relevant to Xcode 13.2.
I haven't gotten my Apple Developer account setup yet, (*that's a nightmare for corporations.*), so I'm trying to get around the 6-day limit for development of an app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of messing with settings, I discovered a working solution that is easy to replicate, and doesn't require any excessive work.

#1. Create another Apple ID. This is free. And, unlike other solutions I've looked at, it doesn't require creating a new one each time your other provisioning file runs out. **USE THE SAME CREDENTIALS OF YOUR OTHER APPLE ID!!!**

#2. Open up your Xcode project. Navigate to the Project properties window.

[image: Xcode Settings]

If you've already logged in to Xcode with an ID, great. If not, do so.

#3.

Click on the 'Team' select button. Click 'Add account' and you'll get the window to add your credentials for your other ID.

[image: Xcode selection]

Click on the newly added Apple ID.

Now, click on the "i" button next to the 'Xcode Managed Profile.'

You should see:

[image: Finale]

Just instead of 3 days, it should be 6 days.

#4. Now, you will have to change your bundle Identifier. ***It does not have to be major, it can simply be the difference between com.myapp.appname and com.myapp.app-name.***
Now, whenever you cannot build because your Prov. file expired, switch your Team Id, and change your bundle id to what it was on that account.

Example: MyAppleId 1: B.I. = com.myapp.appname.

When that expires: MyAppleId 2: B.I. = com.myapp.app-name.
Then, repeat. By the time MyAppleID 2 has expired, MyAppleID 1 is ready again.

Cheers!